# React generate date if form is left blank - Works but only after I cancel the submission

Tags: reactjs, forms, form-submit

I've figured out how to fill a date form with a random date if it is left unfilled within a certain period, but the field is filled only if I cancel the submission.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if(Date === ""){
        let var1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 1) + 1);
        let var2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (12 - 6) + 6);
        if(var1.toString().length === 1){
            var1 = "0" + var1;
        }
        if(var2.toString().length === 1){
            var2 = "0" + var2;
        }
        setDate(var1 + "/" + var2 + "/" + "2021");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    const answer = window.confirm("Please confirm you have entered your information " +
        "correctly.\n" +
        "\nEmail: " + email +
        "\nFirst Name: " + Name +
        "\nLast Name: " + LastName +
        "\nGender: " + Gender +
        "\nAMKA: " + AMKA +
        "\nDate: " + Date);

    if (answer) {
        const url = "...";
        const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, Name, LastName, Gender, AMKA, Date })
        };
        fetch(url, requestOptions)
            .then((response) => console.log("Submitted successfully", requestOptions.body))
            .catch((error) => console.log("Form submit error", error));
    } else {
        console.log("Your submission was not sent.");
    }


};
```

[After I click on Submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpZbl.png)

[Date is filled only if I click on cancel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b6FZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a rookie mistake, I just pushed up my code which handles the date randomization.